# How to convert Nifti file to Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, nifti

I have 3D array in Nifti file (.ii.gz) and I want to save it as a 3D numpy array. I used Nibabel to convert Numpy to Nifti1. Can I do the opposite?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [**`nipy`**](http://nipy.org/nibabel/gettingstarted.html)

```
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib

img = nib.load(example_filename)

a = np.array(img.dataobj)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also do this:

```py
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib
    
img_nifti = nib.load(filepath)
img = img_nifti.get_fdata()
```

Comment: `get_data()` is now deprecated, now you can use `get_fdata()` instead