# How to convert 3D numpy array to nifti image in nibabel?

Tags: python, numpy, nifti, nibabel

From this question [How to convert Nifti file to Numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44422248), I created a 3D numpy array of a nifti image. I made some modifications to this array (changed depth of the array by adding padding of zeroes).

How can I convert this array back to nifti image?

I tried:

```
imga = Image.fromarray(img, 'RGB')
imga.save("modified/volume-20.nii")
```

but it doesn't identify `nii` extension. I also tried:

```
nib.save(img,'modified/volume-20.nii')
```

this is also not working, because `img` must be `nibabel.nifti1.Nifti1Image` if I want to use `nib.save` feature. In both of the examples above `img` is a 3D numpy array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you a **numpy array** and you want to use `nib.save` function, you need to first get the `affine` transformation.

Example:

```
# define the path to the data
func_filename = os.path.join(data_path, 'task-rest_bold.nii.gz')

# load the data
func = nib.load(func_filename)

# do computations that lead to a 3D numpy array called "output"
# bla bla bla
# output = np.array(....)

# to save this 3D (ndarry) numpy use this
ni_img = nib.Nifti1Image(output, func.affine)

nib.save(ni_img, 'output.nii.gz')
```

Now you will be able to overlay the `output.nii.gz` onto the `task-rest_bold.nii.gz`